# Conditional Problems on Trigonometric Ratios

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin A/(1+\sin A) + \sin B/(1+\sin B)=2$ then prove that $(\sec^2 A)(1-\sin  A)+(\sec^2 B)(1-\sin B)=0.$

I tried by rationalization and simplifying I got $(\sin A  \sec^2 A)(1-\sin A)+(\sin B  \sec^2 B)(1-\sin B)=2.$

Answer (score 1):

**Remark:** We will use standard "moves" to show that **if** the given equality holds, **then** the desired equality holds. However, the given equality *does not hold* for any real $A,B$!

Let us close our eyes to this fact, and continue as if we were dealing with a real question.

Subtract $1$ from each term. We get 
$$\frac{\sin A}{1+\sin A}-1+\frac{\sin B}{1+\sin B}-1=0.$$
This simplifies to
$$-\frac{1}{1+\sin A}-\frac{1}{1+\sin B}=0.$$
Change signs, and do your rationalizing procedure.

Comment: At least not for real-number A, B.

Comment: Thanks. Default assumption in this game, but I edited and specified real.

Comment: Nicolas .Reminds me of a Q that I saw here yesterday about a triangle, that American students could answer but Russian students can't. The conditions on the triangle are impossible, so the joke is on the Americans.

Comment: @user254665: Amusing, but perhaps dated. Mathematics education in Russia has suffered in the new century.